# Prove that two groups of functions are isomorphic

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, function-and-relation-composition

The two functions $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $g(x)=\frac{x-1}{x}$ generate, with the operation of function composition, a group $G$ of functions. Prove that this group is isomorphic to the group $S_3$.

I found a solution which is pretty tedious, so I wonder if there are other ways to prove the above statement. So here is my solution:

With composition we can generate the functions:

$f(f(x))=x$, $g(g(x))=\frac{1}{1-x}$, $g(f(x))=1-x$ and $f(g(x))=\frac{x}{x-1}$

To prove that no more functions can be generated by using the functions above, we need to make a table ($*$ denotes function composition):
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
* & x & 1-x & \frac{1}{x} & \frac{x}{x-1} & \frac{x-1}{x} & \frac{1}{1-x} \\
\hline
x & x & 1-x & \frac{1}{x} & \frac{x}{x-1} & \frac{x-1}{x} & \frac{1}{1-x} \\
\hline
1-x & 1-x & x & \frac{x-1}{x} & \frac{1}{1-x} & \frac{1}{x} & \frac{x}{x-1} \\
\hline
\frac{1}{x} & \frac{1}{x} & \frac{1}{1-x} & x & \frac{x-1}{x} & \frac{x}{x-1} & 1-x \\
\hline
\frac{x}{x-1} & \frac{x}{x-1} & \frac{x-1}{x} & \frac{1}{1-x} & x & 1-x & \frac{1}{x} \\
\hline
\frac{x-1}{x} & \frac{x-1}{x} & \frac{x}{x-1} & 1-x & \frac{1}{x} & \frac{1}{1-x} & x \\
\hline
\frac{1}{1-x} & \frac{1}{1-x} & \frac{1}{x} & \frac{x}{x-1} & 1-x & x & \frac{x-1}{x}
\end{array}
$$

Hence no more functions can be generated. After some construction work, it seems that the following function is an isomorphism:
$$
\phi(x)=()
$$
$$
\phi(1-x)=(1,2)
$$
$$
\phi(\frac{1}{x})=(1,3)
$$
$$
\phi(\frac{x}{x-1})=(2,3)
$$
$$
\phi(\frac{x-1}{x})=(1,2,3)
$$
$$
\phi(\frac{1}{1-x})=(1,3,2)
$$

To check wether this is an isomorphism or not, we need to make a similar table with $S_3$:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
* & () & (1,2) & (1,3) & (2,3) & (1,2,3) & (1,3,2) \\
\hline
() & () & (1,2) & (1,3) & (2,3) & (1,2,3) & (1,3,2) \\
\hline
(1,2) & (1,2) & () & (1,2,3) & (1,3,2) & (1,3) & (2,3) \\
\hline
(1,3) & (1,3) & (1,3,2) & () & (1,2,3) & (2,3) & (1,2) \\
\hline
(2,3) & (2,3) & (1,2,3) & (1,3,2) & () & (1,2) & (1,3) \\
\hline
(1,2,3) & (1,2,3) & (2,3) & (1,2) & (1,3) & (1,3,2) & () \\
\hline
(1,3,2) & (1,3,2) & (1,3) & (2,3) & (1,2) & () & (1,2,3)
\end{array}
$$
If we express this table in terms of $\phi$ we get:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
* & \phi(x) & \phi(1-x) & \phi(\frac{1}{x}) & \phi(\frac{x}{x-1}) & \phi(\frac{x-1}{x}) & \phi(\frac{1}{1-x}) \\
\hline
\phi(x) & \phi(x) & \phi(1-x) & \phi(\frac{1}{x}) & \phi(\frac{x}{x-1}) & \phi(\frac{x-1}{x}) & \phi(\frac{1}{1-x}) \\
\hline
\phi(1-x) & \phi(1-x) & \phi(x) & \phi(\frac{x-1}{x}) & \phi(\frac{1}{1-x}) & \phi(\frac{1}{x}) & \phi(\frac{x}{x-1}) \\
\hline
\phi(\frac{1}{x}) & \phi(\frac{1}{x}) & \phi(\frac{1}{1-x}) & \phi(x) & \phi(\frac{x-1}{x}) & \phi(\frac{x}{x-1}) & \phi(1-x) \\
\hline
\phi(\frac{x}{x-1}) & \phi(\frac{x}{x-1}) & \phi(\frac{x-1}{x}) & \phi(\frac{1}{1-x}) & \phi(x) & \phi(1-x) & \phi(\frac{1}{x}) \\
\hline
\phi(\frac{x-1}{x}) & \phi(\frac{x-1}{x}) & \phi(\frac{x}{x-1}) & \phi(1-x) & \phi(\frac{1}{x}) & \phi(\frac{1}{1-x}) & \phi(x) \\
\hline
\phi(\frac{1}{1-x}) & \phi(\frac{1}{1-x}) & \phi(\frac{1}{x}) & \phi(\frac{x}{x-1}) & \phi(1-x) & \phi(x) & \phi(\frac{x-1}{x})
\end{array}
$$

If we compare it to the first table we see that $\phi(f*g)=\phi(f)*\phi(g)$ $\forall f,g \in G$. Since $\phi$ is bijective it's an isomorphism. And therefore, $G$ and $S_3$ are isomorphic.

Is there a way to avoid making those tables? It seems pretty intuitive after trial and error that $\phi$ is an isomorphism, but how can we prove it formally in a neat and elegant way? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A faster way is to note that both groups act on the set $\{0, 1, \infty\}$. The group $S_3$ does as a permutation representation, which is pretty clear. The second one does by viewing this a subset of $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$.

If you then look at the group $G$ of functions, then you can see pretty clearly that the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ acts as the permutation which swaps $0, \infty$, and the function $g(x)$ acts as the 3-cycle $0\to \infty\to 1 \to 0$.

Playing around with these views should help you see a better way to prove this.